# How select data from multiple tables based on some criteria and insert it into a nother table?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm working o a shopping cart with python and flask. I want that when a user clicks on the order button on an item, they are redirected to /cart/add/ route where SQL statement is run to retrieve data such as username from users table, item name and price from allfood table based on the items id passed in the URL and address from delivery_address table. once this info is collected it will also be added to the shopping_cart table where it will be kept temporarily until i figure out the next step. I'm having trouble with the SQL and I was hoping someone could correct it because it's giving me an error.

```
"INSERT INTO shopping_cart_tbl VALUES (username, address, item, cost) \
        SELECT user.username, addr.address, food.item_, food.cost \
        FROM register_tbl AS user FULL JOIN delivery_addresses_tbl AS addr FULL JOIN allfood_tbl AS food \
        ON user.username = addr.username AND food.id=%s"
```

for the sake of knowing if I can improve my code with any suggestions, I'll post the code for the route

```
 @app.route('/cart/add/<item_id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
 def sadd_to_cart(item_id):
    # do a cross join of the three tables maybe to retrieve the necessarinformation
    if 'userkey' in session:
        con = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "", "sampledb")
        cursor_full_join = con.cursor()
        sql="INSERT INTO shopping_cart_tbl VALUES (username, address, item, cost) \
            SELECT user.username, addr.address, food.item_, food.cost \
            FROM register_tbl AS user FULL JOIN delivery_addresses_tbl AS addr FULL JOIN allfood_tbl AS food \
            ON user.username = addr.username AND food.id=%s" 

        cursor_full_join.execute(sql, item_id)

        return render_template('homepage.html')

    elif 'userkey' not in session:
        return redirect('/login')
    else:
        return redirect('/login')
```

I appreciate the help.
edit: i removed unnecessary quotation marks. Sorry. i hadn't noticed them for some reason

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `INSERT INTO shopping_cart_tbl VALUES (username, address, item, cost)` should be `INSERT INTO shopping_cart_tbl (username, address, item, cost)`

Comment: i'm getting pymysql.err.ProgrammingError)1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax)

Comment: i've tried your suggestion and the same error has come about